# How to simulate key pressed event in Qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots, qtvirtualkeyboard

I'm implementing a customized virtual keyboard using QML. My purpose is simulating a physical key press signal of real keyboard when I click a button in virtual keyboard. I have followed the tutorial in [Qt Virtual Keyboard](https://www.wisol.ch/w/articles/2015-07-26-virtual-keyboard-qt/) and have successfully built and run the example code.

The problem is that the example code employs `QCoreApplication::sendEvent()` function in a C++ class to send key press event to focused QObject. It works well when I import *QtQuick.Controls 1.3* in *main.qml* as the guide, but takes no effect when I change to *QtQuick.Controls 2.2*, which is essential in my application. Here is the core of the example code:

```
void KeyEmitter::emitKey(Qt::Key key)
{
    QQuickItem* receiver = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(QGuiApplication::focusObject());
    if(!receiver) {
        return;
    }
    QKeyEvent pressEvent = QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, key, Qt::NoModifier, QKeySequence(key).toString());
    QKeyEvent releaseEvent = QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, key, Qt::NoModifier);
    QCoreApplication::sendEvent(receiver, &pressEvent);
    QCoreApplication::sendEvent(receiver, &releaseEvent);
}
```

So how can I send the key press event to my application?

Comment: Be more specific please. Using QML Controls 2 does your emitKey method is called? Or sendEvent has no effect? Place a breakpoint to the beginning of the emitKey method and see what happens.

Comment: Yes the emitKey() method has been called, but it did not take effect

Answer (score 2):

I think the `focusObject` is the actual clicked button, so sending an `QKeyEvent` to that instead of the `TextField` is pointless.

How about passing the actual receiver object's pointer instead of asking `QGuiApplication` for the `focusObject`.

Try this:

keyemitter.h file (header only, you don't need cpp file):

```
#ifndef KEYEMITTER_H
#define KEYEMITTER_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QKeyEvent>
class KeyEmitter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    KeyEmitter(QObject* parent=nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}
    Q_INVOKABLE void keyPressed(QObject* tf, Qt::Key k) {
        QKeyEvent keyPressEvent = QKeyEvent(QEvent::Type::KeyPress, k, Qt::NoModifier, QKeySequence(k).toString());
        QCoreApplication::sendEvent(tf, &keyPressEvent);
    }
};
#endif // KEYEMITTER_H
```

main.cpp file:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "keyemitter.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;
    KeyEmitter keyEmitter;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("keyEmitter", &keyEmitter);
    view.setSource(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "red"
    Column{
        Row {
            TextField {
                id: tf
                Component.onCompleted: { console.log(tf); }
                text: "123"
            }
        }
        Row {
            Button {
                text: "1"
                onClicked: keyEmitter.keyPressed(tf, Qt.Key_1)
            }
            Button {
                text: "2"
                onClicked: keyEmitter.keyPressed(tf, Qt.Key_2)
            }
            Button {
                text: "3"
                onClicked: keyEmitter.keyPressed(tf, Qt.Key_3)
            }
        }
        Row {
            Button {
                text: "DEL"
                onClicked: keyEmitter.keyPressed(tf, Qt.Key_Backspace)
            }
            Button {
                text: "OK"
                onClicked: keyEmitter.keyPressed(tf, Qt.Key_Enter)
            }
            Button {
                text: "ESC"
                onClicked: keyEmitter.keyPressed(tf, Qt.Key_Escape)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank @Ponzifex,

You are right. When I click the button in my customized keyboard, the focus object immediately changes to the clicked button instead of the textfield as I want.

Simply, changing focusPolicy of the button to NoFocus fixes my problem.

```
Button {
    id: btnOne                
    focusPolicy: Qt.NoFocus
    text: qsTr("1")
    onClicked: {
        keyEmitter.emitKey( Qt.Key_1 )
    }
}
```